# il faut trop que je taste or il faut je taste trop or il faut que je taste trop

Tags: mode-grammatical

**il faut trop que je taste

il faut je taste trop 

il faut que je taste trop**

These three ways are confusing me which one means:
*I have to taste too much*

Comment: A link to the ad, or a picture of it, or a text  if there is no picture, is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

*taste* doesn't exist in French, you have to use the verb

> goûter

instead.

maybe you misread the word and it was

> teste

From the verb *tester = to test*

that can be used as a synonym for *essayer = to try*

Appart from that, the correct structure would be

> Il faut trop que je goûte/teste

also i'm not sure why you use *too much* here, I would have used *so bad* in this context

Comment: It was a chocolate ads appeared to me on Facebook with:<br>
il faut trop que je taste<br>

also using a translator, il faut que je goute trop is also working.<br>
and a french speaking friend said he would say: il faut je goute trop<br>

Comment: unless they kept `taste` as a wordplay with the name of the brand, `taste`doesn't exist in french. 

Also, `que` is mandatory after `falloir` with subjonctive. Some people (especially people born after 2000) tend to remove it to copy the english structure, but this is not correct.

Comment: A ma connaissance, `taster` est une variante désuète de `tâter`. La seule utilisation moderne (bien que très rare) est le "taste-vin" ou "tastevin", coupelle servant à goutter (ou "tâter") le vin. Mais effectivement je n'ai jamais vu "taster" employé hors de ce contexte.

Comment: FWIW, I'm a native and "Il faut trop que je goûte" is also how I would have put it. Omitting "que" is not correct as Flying_whale said. The only word that could be skipped in a not so formal setting is "Il" at the beginning of the sentence. Now, about the question itself, my general advice would be to be extremely cautious about using internet ads as a reference. They are often translated via an automated translator and can be absolutely incorrect or even meaningless in the target language.

Comment: @OsamaAboelfath @Batman maybe I found an explanation for `taste`, did some edit in my reply ;)

Comment: Salut, je pose ça là :) https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/nutilisez-pas-les-blocs-de-code-pour-les-citations-do-not-use-code-blocks-for

Answer (score 0):

Since it was from an ad, maybe it was a play on word between "Taste" and "Teste" (that we could translate by "try").

I think it was first aimed for young people, who first read "Il faut trop que je teste" => "I have to try".
The "trop" here, is only used to emphasis the action. We could translate it by accuenting the verb => "I **have** to try".

And then, they realise that it was "taste" => "goûter" (which can also be translated to "snak time"). So they say to themselves "Wow this chocolate is so cool" (well they would say it in French though, ...).

So I think this sentence was just used for a marketing spot.